# update graph with new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a list of files that I want to plot in order (line graph), creating an animation as d3 transitions between them.

I have an update function that takes as input a file name, and transitions the current line graph to the new line graph. This is working fine.

However, I now want to transition in order between five different files.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var file_list = ["time1.csv", "time2.csv", "time3.csv", "time4.csv", "time5.csv"];

var num_files = file_list.length;

for (i = 0; i < num_files; ++i) {
    setTimeout(setDelay(i), 1000);
}

function setDelay(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    update(file_list[i]);
  }, 1000);
}
```

This does transition my line graph, but it transitions from the first (time1.csv) immediately to the last (time5.csv), skipping everything in the middle.

How can I figure out what is going wrong?

If I console.log(file_list[i]) in the loop, it is looping through and printing time1.csv ... time5.csv.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that "chained transitions" is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setDelay` is called on every iteration, to evaluate it on timeout you must pass the function object as callback `setTimeout(function() { setDelay(i); }, 1000)`

But your logic is wrong, why two `setTimeout` per iteration? All of them is calling immediatly after each iteration, you must chain the `setDelay` calls or multiply the delay by iteration index.

```
var file_list = ["time1.csv", "time2.csv", "time3.csv", "time4.csv", "time5.csv"];

function setDelay() {
    var file = file_list.shift();
    if (file) {
        update(file);
        setTimeout(setDelay, 1000);
    }
}

setDelay();
```